# excel how add an index to filtered cells only

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have selected all rows, via a filter, that have as value in column B, FALSE.

Now i would like, for each cell that has the value false, to add next to it, in a new column, an index, that will count each FALSE value.

Something like a counter. For example

```
A       B
False | 1
False | 2
False | 3
False | 4
```

but only for the visible cells, once i filter for the FALSE value, in column A. How could i do this with a formula in excel?
tried pressing f5, and chose special, and selected visible cells only, but the result was wrong.

Comment: Do you want the index to remain if you remove the filter? or change to fit the filter each time?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following steps,

- Filter and select only FALSE. Column A will be having only FALSE.
- Am assuming cell A2 is the first instance on "FALSE". In this case, use the below formula in cell B2

  =COUNTIF($A$1:A3,"FALSE")
- Double click the fill handle or click and drag for all rows which has "FALSE".
- Even if you remove the filter, you will have the number sequences untouched.

Let me know if you need anything else